# Extract a column from csv file which has few rows with extra commas as value(address field), which causes the column count to break

Tags: python, pandas

I need to access values of a column that occur after the address column, but due to presence of comma in the address field, I causes the file to count extra columns.

Example csv:

```
id,name,place,address,age,type,dob,date
1,Murtaza,someplace,Street,MA,22,B,somedate,somedate,
2,Murtaza,someplace,somestreet,45,C,somedate,somedate,
3,Murtaza,someplace,somestreet,MA,44,V,somedate,somedate
```

Excel output:

```
id  name    place       address    age  type  dob     date     newcolumn9

1  Murtaza someplace  somestreet    MA   22    B      somedate  somedate

2  Murtaza someplace  somestreet    45    C  somedate somedate

3  Murtaza someplace  somestreet    MA   44    V      somedate  somedate
```

This is what I tried:

```
# I was able to see that all columns before the column with extra commas displayed fine using this code. 

import pandas as pd
import csv
with open('Myfile', 'rb') as f, 
   open('Newfile', 'wb') as g:
writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter=',')
for line in f:
    row = line.split(',', 2)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I am trying to do this in python pandas.

If I can parse the csv in reverse ill be able to get the proper values regardless of the error.

From the above example, I want extract `age` column.

Comment: How big is the file? Can you post a few example lines?

Comment: If it's not a valid CSV file, you'll need to write your own code to parse it, you can't use a standard library.

Comment: You need to provide more details. If  by "extra commas" you mean that certain rows have more "columns" than others, a csv parser can still handle that, but `pandas` won't be able to put that into a data-frame, since it expects trict, tabular data. However, if the column you are interested in is always X columns from the right, then it should be relatively easy to extract this with the `csv` module.

Comment: It would probably be best if you could show us the first dozen or so lines in the csv file.

Comment: @MurtazaHaji Again, you need to provide **details**. Not simply restate in a comment what you already have in your question. You also need to add information *to the question itself*, not as a comment. Do you really expect people to try to read that code you posted in a comment?

Comment: im sorry i was new to stackoverflow and i did not understand that asking questions is a privilege. i have become really alert now and ask only relevant questions with proper code. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

panda, or simply `re.split()`:

```
import re

your_csv_file=open('your_csv_file.csv','r').read()
i_column=2      #index of desired column, counted from back
lines=re.split('\n',your_csv_file)[:-1] #eventually remove last (empty) line
your_column=[]
for line in lines:
  your_column.append(re.split(',',line)[-i_column])    #the minus affects indexing beginning at the end
print(your_column)
```

executed on a .csv-file like the one below

```
4rth,askj,fpou,ABC,aekert
kjgf,poiuf,pejhh,,oeiu,DEF,akdhg
iuzrit,fslgk,gth,,rhf,,rhe,GHI,ozug
pwiuto,,,,eflgjkhrlguiazg,JKL,rgj
```

this returns

```
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL']
```

Comment: Is something missing from the first sentence?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank u so much bro Really apologize for the way i asked the question but im hoping to improve just starting of being a programmer

Comment: @SimSon What does "pandas, or simply re.split()" mean? It looks like a sentence fragment.

Comment: "[You could use] panda, or simply [do] `re.split()`", sorry

Comment: Can u give me the snippet for parsing in forward direction and extracting the first column as well. @SimSon

Comment: The minus in `[-i_column]` at `your_column.append(re.split(',',line)[-i_column])` does the trick. `re.split()` returns a list, negative indices are counted from the end of the list, positive indices from the start

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this might be to write a separate script that removes the faulty commas.  But if you want to just ignore the faulty lines, then that can be done by reading in each line into a StringIO and ignore the line with the incorrect number of commas.  So if you're expecting 4 columns:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import pandas

s = StringIO()
correct_columns = 4
with open('MyData.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        if len(','.split(line)) == correct_columns:
            s.write(line)
s.seek(0)
pandas.read_csv(s)
```

Comment: Exactly, im sorry but this comment didnt help me at all. @Graydyn Young